# How to modify the code such that can call usehook using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

A popup is displayed when the add button is clicked and the count is greater or less than 0.

below is the code,

```
function AddButton () {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const count = useGetCount();
    useTrigger(isOpen, count);
    const on_add_click = ()  => {
        setIsOpen(true);
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={on_add_click}>add</button>
    );  
}


interface ContextProps {
    trigger: (count: number) => void;
}

const popupContext = React.createContext<ContextProps>({
    trigger: (count: number) => {},
});

const usePopupContext = () => React.useContext(popupContext);

export const popupContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
    const limit = 0;

    const dismiss = () => {
        if (show) {
            sessionStorage.setItem(somePopupId, 'dismissed');
            setShow(false);
        }

    };

    const isDismissed = (dialogId: string) =>
        sessionStorage.getItem(dialogId) === 'dismissed';

        const context = {
            trigger: (count: number) => {
            if (!isDismissed(somePopupId) && count <= limit) {
                setShow(true);
            } else if (count > limit) {
                setShow(false);
            }
        },
    };

    return (
        <popupContext.Provider value={context}>
            {children}
            {show && (
                <Popup onHide={dismiss} />
            )}
        </popupContext.Provider>
    );
};


export function useTrigger(enabled: boolean, count: number) {
    const { trigger } = usePopupContext();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (enabled) {
            trigger(count);
        }
    }, [enabled, count, trigger]);
}
```

This works but calls trigger method only when enabled is true.

I want to modify the above code such that when the user clicks the add button, I want this useTrigger to happen. I don't want to check for enabled and call trigger.

I have tried the following removed checking for enabled.

```
export function useTrigger(enabled: boolean, count: number) {
    const { trigger } = usePopupContext();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        trigger(count);
    }, [enabled, count, trigger]);
}
```

this works but the popup is displayed as the count is less than or equal to 0. but I want it to first check if the add button clicked or not.

so soon after the user clicking the add button in on_add_click I want the popup to display.
How can I modify the code above? I am new to using hooks. Could someone help me with this? thanks.

EDIT:**strong text**
i have tried to do something like below and i get error

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

```
on_add_click = () => {
    Trigger(count);
}

export function Trigger(count: number) {
    const { trigger } = usePopupContext();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        trigger(count);
    }, [count, trigger]);
}
```

how can i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you right, you just need to add a state to your hook and return the setter to call it onclick:

```
export function useTrigger(count: number) {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false)
    const { trigger } = usePopupContext();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if(clicked) {
            trigger(count);
        }
 
    }, [count, trigger, clicked]);
    const clickCb = useCallback(() => {setClicked(true)}, [])
    return cb
}
```

Then in your component with button you do something like this:

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const onClick = useTrigger(props.count)
    /* ... */
    return <button onClick={onClick}/>
}
```

Comment: thanks this almost works. but the clicked state is set to false when user clicks a button that redirects him to main page (history.push (/home). and it doesnt call trigger method in useEffect. this popup is visible in all pages so redirecting to home page on clicking button should still keep clicked state to true. could you help me with this. thanks.

Comment: I see. I think the best approach for you would be to lift the `clicked` state to the `contextProvider` and keep it there then retrieve it as well as the callback using the `usePopupContext` hook

Comment: thanks could you please modify your answer to this such that i can accept it as well.